# Failed Http Web Request - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I know there has been many questions and answers about this error, but I have tried all suggestions I could find and nothing has worked.

I am using c# WebRequest to connect to an API and I get this error:
`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`

I tried upgrading from .NET 4.0 to 4.72 and it did not solve.

I tried adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.

Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10.

According to an online SSL test, the target system has TLS 1.3 and TLS 1.2 enabled only.

Cipher Suites:

## TLS 1.3 (suites in server-preferred order)

TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256

TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256

## TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 256

Is this supported by my server, or anything else I can try?

Current code is:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Remove the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` and `.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` entirely. You **do not** need those in Windows Server 2019 (in Windows 7, maybe; or for testing purposes. For nothing else). TLS 1.3 is not supported in that System (only experimental, on demand) -- Update to .NET Framework 4.8 (.NET 7+ if possible) and use HttpClient instead of WebRequest -- Take [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) (free software), to see what's available / enabled in that machine, and the ordering of the Cipher Suites

Comment: The required Cipher Suites for TLS 1.2 are [available in your Server version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1809) (see also the NIST Technical documentation you find there) -- See also [How to deploy custom cipher suite ordering in Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/deploy-custom-cipher-suite-ordering) -- [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-)

Comment: If it fails anyway and you cannot determine the cause, use a Proxy / network protocol analyzer as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the TLS transaction in real time

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I removed the callback, tried setting to TLS1.2, but no luck. Updated my test site to 4.8 but attempting to use System.Net.HttpClient says namespace not found.

Comment: Oops... I meant use System.Net.Http.

Comment: Ok, got HttpClient going but similar error `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, check with IIS Crypto (or similar tool) what is enabled in that machine (assuming it's been updated regularly). If everything seems OK (that tool also allow to enable recommended combinations of settings, if that's needed), then use a tool as Wireshark to identify the actual issue, e.g., why the SSL/TLS transaction is aborted and which part is doing that. I.e., you have to verify that the protocol is active and the cipher suites are actually available in your test machine

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much access to the server (shared hosting). My code does work if I run on my local Win 10 PC. I have just tried doing the same thing in PHP on the same server and it is able to access the same URLs without error.